# ошибка при выполнении процедур в пакете package oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle, package

Добрый день пытаюсь разобраться c пакетами в oracle sql, создаю пакет:

```
create or replace package nsv_pkg_testrand is
    procedure clear;
    procedure fill_table(coll int);
    FUNCTION stick_by_data(string_rand varchar2, number_rand number) RETURN varchar2;
    function stick_by_id(id int) return varchar2;
end nsv_pkg_testrand;

    create or replace package body nsv_pkg_testrand is 
    procedure clear is
        begin
            delete from nsv_testrand;
        end clear;
        
    procedure fill_table(coll int) is
        begin
            insert into su.nsv_testrand(string_rand, number_rand)
            select  
                dbms_random.string('A', 5) str, 
                round(dbms_random.value(11111,99999)) numbers 
            from dual connect by level <= coll;
        end fill_table;
        
    function stick_by_data (string_rand varchar2, number_rand number) RETURN varchar2 
    is
        res varchar2(242);
    begin
       res := '123';
       return res;
    end;
    
    function stick_by_id(id int) return varchar2
    is
        res varchar2(242);
    begin
        res:= '123';
        return res;
    end;
end nsv_pkg_testrand;
```

Но при попытке использовать процедуру или функцию:

```
nsv_pkg_testrand.clear;
```

выходит ошибка:

> > Error starting at line : 26 in command - nsv_pkg_testrand.clear Error report - Unknown Command

Вот вопрос где ошибка то?
Если создать просто процедуры то работает нормально

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `function stick_by_data` - отсутствует указание завершения текста функции в её финальном `end;`. Соответственно следующее `function stick_by_id(id int) return varchar2` воспринимается как продолжение тела предыдущей функции.

Comment: @Akina Удалил функции вообще, все равно та же ошибка, может бы что пакеты не работают рпосто из кода? а только из процедур и т.д. Не могу понять :-(

Comment: номер ошибки какой?

Comment: Ну я бы вообще, чисто по логике, сперва создавал бы процедуры и функции, и только потом - объединяющий их пакет.

Comment: может быть `begin nsv_pkg_testrand.clear; end;`

Comment: @AlexR.
Все что выходит в Script Output:
Error starting at line : 28 in command -
su.nsv_pkg_testrand.clear
Error report -
Unknown Command
Никого номера не вижу

Comment: @AlexR.сработало, огромное спасибо! :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В Oracle объекты PL/SQL (процедуры и функции) не могут вызываться вне sql команд *insert*, *update*, *delete*

Их вызов должен быть заключен в анонимный блок

```
begin 
  nsv_pkg_testrand.clear; 
end;
```